# I've created a simple program but something is not right

Tags: c++

It works if I would remove the "=" sign on the for loop condition. But when I add an equal sign to it, it will crash after the first loop. So to sum up, the first loop will work but not the second one. Help please and thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int arrayValue;

  cout << "Enter an array value: ";
  cin >> arrayValue;
  cout << endl;

  string names[arrayValue];

  for (int x = 0; x <= arrayValue; x++) {
    cout << "Enter a name for no." << x << ": ";
    cin >> names[x];
  }

  cout << "No."
       << "  ------  "
       << "Value" << endl;

  for (int j = 0; j <= arrayValue; j++) {
    cout << j << "  ------  " << names[j] << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you know how to fix the code (by removing the `=`), why are you here?

Comment: So just remove the "=" sign on the for loop condition ;)

Comment: @ScottHunter cos im new to c++ sir and i want to know why it's crashing whenever i add the "=" sign

Comment: It crashes because the last iteration of the first for loop tries to access `arrayValue'th` index which exceeds the last index of your array ( which goes from `0` to `arrayValue-1` ) and it causes a crash. It doesn't crash after the first loop, it crashes during the last iteration of the first for loop.

Comment: Variable Length Arrays [VLA] are not supported in C++.  The statement `string names[arrayValue];` is a VLA.  Use `std::vector<std::string>` or dynamically allocate the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know, that arrays start on 0, so, to access your array values, you must iterate from 0 to size-1.

There is your problem, when you put the <= you will iterate until the size, not until the last position.

So, to sum up, when you iterate an array, you must cover it's positions that start in 0, so using i < size is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

string names[arrayValue]; is not working like you intented, a array must be initialized with a fixed size before the program is run. Possible solution to your program could be

```
const uint32_t maxSize = 1024; // 1024 being a upper limit
string names[maxSize];

for (int x = 0; x <= arrayValue; x++) {
    if (x >= (maxSize - 1)) // remember a array of size 1024 goes from 0 to 1023 
        break;
    cout << "Enter a name for no." << x << ": ";
    cin >> names[x];
}
```

other way to write it without the if-check:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= arrayValue && x < maxSize; x++)
```

or you could use a vector (a vector is a dynamic array that can grow and shrink):

```
#include <vector>
vector<string> names;

for (int x = 0; x <= arrayValue; x++) {
    cout << "Enter a name for no." << x << ": ";
    string n;
    cin >> n;
    names.push_back(n);
}
```

Comment: It is non standard for C++, but commonly supported by compilers (because it's part of C language). I don't suppose it's the issue here.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen How can the compiler know how much space to allocate on the stack when it needs the user input? As he does not initialize the int in the start of the function wouldn't the array have a undefined / random size?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't C language too well, so I can't answer *how* does it work. But [Variable Length Arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) are a thing since C99. And gcc for example allows the same when compiling C++ code (will emit a warning with `-Wpedantic` iirc).

Comment: I see, I haven't used gcc much so I didn't know this was possible (my compiler wouldn't allow it), but i think its better to stick to the standard.